# Can't see Sleuth spanId or traceId in custom logback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

logback configuration is down below

```
    <appender name="ELK-CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                    {
                        "timestamp": "@timestamp",
                        "severity": "%level",
                        "service": "${springAppName:-}",
                        "trace": "%X{traceId:-}",
                        "span": "%X{spanId:-}",
                        "pid": "${PID:-}",
                        "thread": "%thread",
                        "class": "%logger{40}",
                        "rest": "%message"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

But span or trace is always null ,

```
{
    "timestamp":"@timestamp",
    "severity":"INFO",
    "service":"springAppName_IS_UNDEFINED",
    "trace":"",
    "span":"",
    "pid":"21524",
    "thread":"reactor-http-nio-3",
    "class":"elk-logger",
    "rest":"test log content"
}
```

Not sure is there is any configuraiton that i'm missing, Thanks for any advice

I tried %X{X-B3-TraceId:-} ,But still doesn't work

```
"trace": "%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}",
"span": "%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some possible reasons why you can't see Sleuth spanId or traceId in your custom logback configuration.

- One reason is that you need to include the Sleuth pattern in your log pattern, which is %X{traceId:-} %X{spanId:-} %X{parentId:-}.
- Another reason is that you need to include the base.xml file from Spring Boot, which contains the default configuration for Sleuth logging.
- A third reason is that you need to set the logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.sleuth property to DEBUG or higher

I hope this helps you solve your problem. If you want to learn more about Sleuth and Logback, you can check out these resources:
•  [Get Current Trace ID in Spring Cloud Sleuth](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-sleuth-get-trace-id): A tutorial on how to get the current trace ID and span ID using the Tracer object.

Comment: Thanks! I included the base.xml  and change pattern to %X{traceId:-} %X{spanId:-} ,it works! Since sleuth 3.x  pattern %X{X-B3-TraceId:-} %X{X-B3-SpanId:-} is no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Follow reference configuration at https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sleuth-documentation-apps/blob/main/service1/src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/2.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#json-logback-with-logstash

**(2)**

```java
logging.pattern.level=%5p[${spring.zipkin.service.name:${spring.application.name:-}},%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}]
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/2.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#features

Answer (score 0):

This configuration works only when you set **w3c propagation**.

```
spring:
  sleuth:
    propagation:
      type: w3c
```